# Transfering files from one directory to another via python

Tags: python, linux, directory, move, transfer

I'm trying to move multiple files from one directory to another. 
The function I'm trying to make should move files if they begin with a value in `sample_list`. My issue is that there are multiple files which begins with a value in `sample_list`, this seems to be causing issues for shutil.

```
import shutil
import os

source = './train/'
dest1 = './test/'

files = [
 '195_reg_6762_1540.npz',
 '1369_reg_7652_-2532.npz',
 '195_reg_1947_-484.npz',
 '1336_reg_6209_1217.npz',
 '1198_reg_3784_-934.npz',
 '12_reg_3992_-10.npz',
 '1369_reg_3214_-91.npz']

test_samples = [195, 1493, 409, 339, 12, 1336]

#Move files which begin with values in test_samples  [edited orig post to fix typo]
for f in files:
    for i in test_samples:
        if (f.startswith(str(i))):
            shutil.move(source+f, dest1)
```

Raises the error:

```
  File "/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 564, in move
    raise Error("Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst)

Error: Destination path '/home/usr/Documents/project/data/test/195_reg_1947_-484.npz' already exists
```

It always fails if there is more than one file with a value in test samples to move. 
What would be the correct way to move files which begin with values in `test_samples` from `source` directory to `target` directory.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when you've already successfully run the script (or parts of it once). Once the file exists in the destination directory, shutil throws an exception if you try to replace it.

See this modification that checks if the file already exists in the destination directory and, if so, deletes it and moves it back from the origin directory (note that the file must exist again in the origin directory). [Do you mean to copy instead of move?]

```
for f in files:
    for i in test_samples:
        if (f.startswith(str(i))):
            if not os.path.exists(dest1+f):
                shutil.move(source+f, dest1)
            else:
                os.remove(dest1+f)
                shutil.move(source+f,dest1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the respone. Could you clarify what you mean by 'must exist again in origin directory'? Running your given code gives `https://pastebin.com/EanZDN4L` .   No, my goal is to transfer files from source to dest1, the transferred  files should only exist is dest1.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. So this script is moving files from source to dest1. As soon as you run this script successfully once, the files no longer exist in source. If you recopy the files to source but then do not delete the files from dest1 and run your original script, you'll get the error you received because the files were already moved and exist in dest1.

Comment: To see what I mean, use the code I provided and start with all 7 files in the source directory. Try running the script. It should run successfully. Now, put a copy of all 7 files back in the source directory (but leave a copy of the moved files in the dest1 directory) and try running your script. you'll get that error again because the files already exist in dest1. Now try running my script. You'll see the script complete successfully because it checks whether the file exists before moving it again.